# Respond_to in combination with aliassing a method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In a plugin I am writing I am using alias to override one of the default Rails validators like so:

```
# Alias the original validator so it's still available under a different name
alias original_validates_uniqueness_of :validates_uniqueness_of unless method_defined?(:original_validates_uniqueness_of)
# Then alias the custom validator under the original name
alias validates_uniqueness_of :custom_validates_uniqueness_of
```

This all works pretty well. When "validates_uniqueness_of" is defined on an attribute in a AR model, it will use my "custom_validates_uniqueness_of" method instead. Validations are running as expected.

However, when I call:

```
SomeARclass.respond_to?(:validates_uniqueness_of)
```

..it will return false. This behavior will mess with several popular plugins.

**My question**:
Why is respond_to returning "false"? Is this behavior the result of alliasing? How can adjust my custom validator to make it return true?

Thank you for your help.
Erwin

Comment: Did you try defining an actual method that calls the aliased one?

Comment: Is `scoped_validates_uniqueness_of` a `private` method?

Comment: @Justice: this was actually the problem, it was a private method. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. If you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample, on the surface, looks like it should work. I expect you've found that, inside of the class body for `class SomeARclass`, you actually can call `validates_uniqueness_of`.

```
class SomeARclass
  validates_uniqueness_of :first_field # works
end
```

However, I expect that `scoped_validates_uniqueness_of` is a private method. That's why you have been unable to send that message to `SomeARclass` from outside of its class body.

```
SomeARclass.validates_scoped_uniqueness_of :first_field # fails
#=> NoMethodError: private method "validates_scoped_uniqueness_of" called
    for SomeARclass:Class
```

When you alias a private method with a new name, such as aliasing the private method `validates_scoped_uniqueness_of` with the new name `validates_uniqueness_of`, then that new method is also private. I expect that's what happened here.

The documentation for `#respond_to?` reads:

> `- (Boolean) respond_to?(symbol, include_private = false)`
>
> Returns `true` if *obj* responds to the given method. Private methods are included in the search only if the optional second parameter evaluates to `true`.